# Replace Nth match of regex with sed

Tags: regex, sed, replace

I've got a dataset that looks like:

```
1099511629352|Nunez|Jorge|female|17/11/2000|2011-04-04T05:54:52.693+0000|201.221.59.59|Opera|Facebook
```

Column separator in this case is `|` -> I want to replace the Nth column (`$pos`) given one row's id, using sed.

Here's what I've come up with now:

- Find the Nth match of the regex `[$columnsep]*[a-zA-Z0-9./\-:+]+`
- Of a line that starts with the given `$id`
- Replace that occurence with `$columnsep$editvalue`

So the appropriate sed command would be:

```
sed "/^$id/[$columnsep]*[a-zA-Z0-9./\-:+]+/$columnsep$editvalue/$pos}" $file
```

I get `[a- ...": invalid command code [` although it works with online regex testers like https://regexr.com/

Comment: This is a trivial job for `awk`. Why do you need `sed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do the job unless `$columnsep` is longer than one character.

```
sed "/^$id/s/[$columnsep]*[^$columnsep]*/$columnsep$editvalue/$pos" "$file"
```

But, I suggest using awk for tasks like this

```
awk -F "$columnsep" -v OFS="$columnsep" -v id="$id" -v editvalue="$editvalue" -v pos="$pos" '
  ($1==id){$pos=editvalue}1' "$file"
```